# Elasticsearch/Lucene: Query to Find a Word Near the Start or End of a Document

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Is there a way to build an elastic search query that matches documents if a given term appears within *x* spaces of the start of a document?

I understand that I can use `span_near` and `slop` to find all instances of a term that is within *x* spaces of another term, but I don't know how to find instances where the term is near the start or end of a document.

The motivation here is because I have a set of documents that always start with a particular set of words, and I want to be able to query based only on that first word. I understand I can re-index my documents, pull out the first word into another field, and then query that separately, but I would prefer to not have to re-index everything just for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried *span_first*? Looks like what you need.

Comment: Ga... how did I miss that, thanks! Is there anything similar for finding the end? I didn't see a `span_last`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about the end. You want something like this I guess: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanPositionCheckQuery.html but I don't know what is the query equivalent to this in elasticsearch.